# Def не принимает значения

Tags: python

```
def A(a):
    a=input()
    s=a.split()
    for i in [s]:
        if "Amount" in i:
            s2=int(s[2])
            s4=int(s[4])
        if s4<s2:
            print("Heey input corectly")
            break
        for i1 in range(int(s2), int(s4)):
            s4 += i1
        return(s4)

print(A("Amout to 1 to 6"))
```

Пожалуйста, не нужны ссылки на другие материалы с форумов. Я не нашел подобной проблемы нигде, я буду рад принять ваши личные объяснения. Программист начального уровня и, хотя я многого не понимаю, не судите строго

Python-код без попыток превратить в def

```
a=input()
s=a.split()
for i in [s]:
    if "Amount" and "from" in i:
        s2=int(s[2])
        s4=int(s[4])
    if s4<s2:
        print("Heey input corectly")
        break
    for i1 in range(int(s2), int(s4)):
        s4 += i1
    print(s4)
```

Answer (score 3):

А зачем тебе `Input()`?
Ты в `def` подаешь некое значение, а потом пытаешься его считать. Убери в `def A(a):` строку 
`a.input()`

Comment: + Все вышеуказанные замечания

Answer (score 2):

Как то так:

```
def A(a):
    s4 = ''
    s=a.split()

    if "Amount" in s[0]:
        s2=int(s[2])
        s4=int(s[4])
        if s4<s2:
            print("Heey input corectly")
        for i1 in range(int(s2), int(s4)):
            s4 += i1
    else:
        print ("Amount нет в ", s[0])


    return(s4)

print(A("Amount to 1 to 6"))
```

У Вас там была опечатка в последней строке: "Amout", плюс табуляции стояли неправилно, плюс переменная s4 использовалась неинициализированной.

Comment: Спасибо. Я возьму на заметку